# How to extract the type library for 3rd party IM Client using lync sdk?

Tags: com, outlook, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am writing an IM Client using the steps mentioned in the article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx . My client is working fine (except events) if lync is installed in the system but failing if uninstalled the lync client (No lync client installerd). In the article it's mentioned that:

**Important:** The type library for the required interfaces is embedded in Lync 2013/Skype for Business. For third-party integrators, this works only when both Lync 2013 and Skype for Business are installed on the target machine. **If you are integrating using Office Standard, you need to extract the type library and install it on the target machine.** The Lync 2013 SDK includes the Microsoft.Office.UC.dll file.

Now I am stuck here. how to extract the type library for the required interface? I tried to extract if from 'Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll' as below but got errors as below:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>RegAsm.exe /tlb "C:\requiredTlb\Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll"
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.6.1055.0 for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.6.1055.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully

RegAsm : error RA0000 : CLR assembly 'C:\requiredTlb\Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll' was imported from a type library and cannot be re-exported to a type library.  Make sure the type library from which the assembly was imported is registered.

Please help me in this regards. I am new to COM Programming so don't know how to proceed.

Thanks,
Dileep